# Calling a void function in main.dart from another dart file

Tags: function, flutter, call, void

Thanks in advance....

I have an App built with Flutter whereby the main.dart file has a void function. I have another dart file with a raised button that i would like to call the void function from the main.dart file

is this possible??

```
//This is the void in the main.dart file


 void buildBottomSheet(double height, MedicineModel model) async {
   var medicineId = await showModalBottomSheet(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(45), topRight: Radius.circular(45))),
       context: context,
       isScrollControlled: true,
       builder: (context) {
         return FadeAnimation(
            .6,
           AddMedicine(height, model.getDatabase(), 
           model.notificationManager),
         );
       });

  if (medicineId != null) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Reminder Added!",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM_LEFT,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Theme
            .of(context)
            .accentColor,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 20.0);

    setState(() {});
      }
     }   //and then a raised button in a different .dart file to call this void?
```

Comment: Can you show us a code example?

Comment: thanks marsh-wiggle

Comment: do you get any errors? I think you should be okay with this. just import the main.dart to whatever file you have the RaisedButton in

Comment: hi Jose Georges, thank you. But yep, errors are there. i have imported main.dart yet it still says the buildBottomSheet is not defined for type MyApp

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to `call like MyApp.buildBottomSheet(); where MyApp is the class name.`
**But it is not good practice to call function from the main.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 void buildBottomSheet(double height, MedicineModel model) async {
      //custom function
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and your time, however, I import the main.dart and call as you suggested: MyApp.buildBottomSheet()  but it still says that buildBottomSheet isn't defined for the type MyApp.

Comment: kindly share your main.dart file.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, but now the issue is solved. I have started from scratch and now not calling function from main.dart file as @Muhammad Tameem Rafay advised. But thank you anyway